# How would I update all p elements after retrieving data from a server?

Tags: jquery

I've got a script to retrieve the data from a website. The retrieval works fine, but the p colour CSS aren't updated. I'm not sure why/how it isn't being updated, could anyone lend me a hand?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.get("https://randomname.com/getName.php", {name: "fname"}, 
        function (data) { 
         $("body").append("Name: " + data.name + "");},
        "json"
        );
        $("p").css("color", "blue");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("body").after("Name: " + data.name + "");}`
It may works.